# Stubbing a read only property with Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, .net, rhino-mocks

I have a class with a private set property that I want to stub out with rhino mocks.  When I try to do this, though, it gives me a compile time error saying I can't set a read only property.  I'm new to using Rhino Mocks so I must be missing something here...

```
public Interface IFoo
{
    int Quantity { get; }
}

[TestMethod]
public void SomeTest()
{
    IFoo foo = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IFoo>();
    foo.Quantity = 5;

    //Asserts and such
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use:

```
foo.Stub (f => f.Quantity).Return (5);
```

See http://ayende.com/Wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx#UsingExpecttosetupproperties

You can also use:

```
foo.Expect(f => f.Quantity).Return (5);
```

Comment: Using the Stub method worked perfect after I realized I was trying to stub the concrete class rather than the interface.  Thanks!

Comment: I found that `Expect` doesn't work if the property is called multiple time as the second time onwards the original property implementation was called - in this case `Stub` was actually what I wanted.

Comment: Tried with Rhino 3.6.1 and doesn't work: "You are trying to set an expectation on a property that was defined to use PropertyBehavior"... I hate legacy code

Answer (score 4):

You can just do:

```
foo.Stub(f => f.Quantity).Return(5);
//asserts
```